# Sync a live server with a cloned vm?

Tags: vmware

I am using virtual machine workstation 8 and have virtualized a live server.
I would like to know if its possible for the VM to sync with the server so there
is always a up to date backup of the live server?

Im not sure if syncing is possible at all but if anyone else knows of a way to do this
i would greatly appreciate it if you could share your knowledge.

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of syncing are you referring to? What server are you running?

Answer (score 0):

A Virtual Machine behaves 95% identically to a physical server.  How you would "sync" it with another server is identical to how you would do it with two physical servers.

If you're talking about wanting to have both a virtual and physical server kept exactly the same... you're probably going to be working 10x harder than you need to.  It's typically easier/cheaper to setup a cluster for the important services you have...